# Always returning empty result instance

Tags: c#, sql

I need to check whether the user is opted for message alter or not for that I need to get the status and date of member by passing id. But my result set looks like always returning empty  result instance. How do I update the properties?
 Can someone tell me what is wrong with my code.

Model:

```
public class SmsStatus
{
    public string Status { get; set; }
    public DateTime OptInDate { get; set; }
}
```

Method :

```
public static SmsStatusResult GetSmsStatus(string memberNumber)
{     
        var status = "";
        var OptInDate = "";  

    var smsStatusResult = new SmsStatusResult();

    if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(memberNumber))
    {
        using (
            var connection =
                new OracleConnection(
                    ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["OracleMemberConnectionString"].ConnectionString))
        {
            connection.Open();

               using (
                    var command =
                        new OracleCommand(
                            "SELECT sms_status,sms_opt_in_date FROM member WHERE member_nbr = :memberNumber", connection))
                {
                    command.Parameters.Add(
                        new OracleParameter(
                            "memberNumber",
                            OracleDbType.Varchar2,
                            memberNumber,
                            ParameterDirection.Input));




                    using (var reader = command.ExecuteReader())
                    {
                        while (reader.Read())
                        {
                            status = reader["sms_status"].ToString();
                            OptInDate = reader["sms_opt_in_date"].ToString();
                        }
                    }
            }
        }
    }
    return smsStatusResult;
}
```

Comment: Changing a question in a way that invalidates existing answers is impolite IMO. I would suggest rolling back to an earlier version. Next, if the changed code *still* has the same problem, have you debugged into it? What happened? Does `memberNumber` have the expected value? Are you able to read the database entry?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You name your parameter incorrectly. You must replace `member_nbr` by `memberNumber` like this

```
        using (var command = new OracleCommand(
                                        "SELECT sms_status,sms_opt_in_date FROM member WHERE member_nbr = :memberNumber", connection))
        {
            command.Parameters.Add(
                                    new OracleParameter(
                                    "memberNumber",
                                    OracleDbType.Varchar2,
                                    memberNumber,
                                    ParameterDirection.Input));
        }        

            SmsStatus data;
            using (var reader = command.ExecuteReader())
            {
                while (reader.Read())
                {
                    data = new SmsStatus();
                    data.status = reader["sms_status"].ToString();
                    data.OptInDate = reader["sms_opt_in_date"].ToString();
                    //add data to an array if there is multi rows in result
                    //or break if there is only one line
                    break;
                }
            }
            return data;
```

Comment: Edited my code as suggested and added command.ExecuteReader() to update the properties. I am not sure have done right

Comment: Thanks!! I appreciate it. Sorry I missing to add one more thing. My model smsstatus class is referencing  
public class SmsStatusResult : OperationResult
    {
        public SmsStatus SmsStatus { get; set; }
    }
So I changed the SmsStatus to SmsStatusResult data; So my problem is I am getting assembly reference missing. How do I add the assembly reference?

Comment: there is a lot example how to do this i.e https://m.youtube.com/watch?v=5QXav2r1piE

Answer (score 1):

Note: this answer was written before the OP changed the question to fix the problems listed here.

There are two immediate problems:

- Your parameter is called `memberNumber` in the SQL, but you're creating an `OracleParameter` called `member_nbr`
- The first problem would show up if you ever *executed* the command, but at the moment you don't: you create it and add a parameter, but then don't do anything with it

You almost certainly want to execute it, then use the results to modify `smsStatusResult`. If you look at `smsStatusResult`, you're creating an "empty" instance, and then not making any changes to it. So yes, it will always return that "empty" instance.

Comment: Nice eyes. 1 plus.

Comment: @NVP: I'm not going to write the code for you - partly as you won't learn nearly as much that way, and partly because we don't know which part of it you aren't able to do yourself. Do you know how to execute an `OracleCommand` and read the results? If you tell us what specific aspect of this you're having problems with, that's fine - but Stack Overflow isn't a code writing service.

Comment: @NVP: Although I now see you've changed your question so that half of my answer looks like I just didn't read your code. I consider that to be pretty rude.